# react native uploading multiple large files(+40) best practices

Tags: reactjs, react-native, upload

this is a little bit generic question regarding best practices regarding uploading multiple files
so i am making app where user can upload 40+ image at once
since it can be done with fetch or axios but i am afraid of performance issues
like to put to much pressure on js since it is single threaded or causing a crash because of ram usage
what would be the best approach to this like

1-trying to zip the files then upload
2-multi uploading at once
3-uploading one by one
4-other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to upload images in background thread and show upload progress in notification trey. try this library for upload https://github.com/Vydia/react-native-background-upload#readme.